# Можно ли из сообщения CDC получить информацию о типах колонок в таблице YDB?

Tags: ydb

Можно ли из сообщения [CDC](https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/concepts/cdc) получить информацию о типах колонок в таблице YDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока нет, сейчас эти сведения можно получить только через DescribeTable в SDK.